# why selenium try to connect to localhost at "X" port

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, chrome-web-driver

I am new to selenium, Trying out following 

    `File f = new File("/usr/bin/google-chrome");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", f.getAbsolutePath());
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    //wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");`

Empty chrome tab been opening but url "www.google.com" not loading. After few seconds getting error

```
exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:11037/status] to be available after 20002 ms
```

1. Why it is trying to connect localhost at "X"(changing) instead of loading google webpage.
2. How can i overcome this one getting same problem with Firefox also occuring.

Answer (score 1):

**`UnreachableBrowserException`** normally occurs when your code fails to connect with browser. It may be because of your driver executable or browser executable.

Please check -

- Selenium Server jar version compatibility with browser version.
- Path of driver executable.
- Version of executable (based on browser version)

If issue exists then please mention build info and system info in the exception details.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","your path to chrome driver.exe file ");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

**Try this**

My path is `//users//hari//chromedriver.exe`